# In "Sherlock" S2E01, when Irene Adler was negotiating with Mycroft at the end, why didn’t Mycroft just take her phone?

Tags: sherlock

At the *Sherlock* S2E01 end scene, where Irene, Sherlock, and Mycroft were all sitting in that large room together negotiating Irene’s demands, it’s seen that Irene literally just puts the phone with the blackmail data on the table to Mycroft.

I was very confused about this scene; I thought the phone was the store of all the blackmail information. If she just hands the phone over, all Mycroft has to do is take it from her, and then she won’t be able to do any blackmailing.

Comment: Is the phone stated to be the only place that has the photos?  (As opposed to simply being a convenient way to carry around proof of the photos.)  If the photos only lived on the phone, it wouldn't be so important to unlock it, they could just shred it.

Comment: When I take a photo on my phone it instantly transfers to my cloud account. Stealing my phone would have no impact on my ability to access that photo.

Comment: @iandotkelly I thought it might be a duplicate, but the linked answer only deals with why Sherlock didn't destroy the phone, not with why Mycroft / British government didn't

Comment: @svavil Answers (generally) don't matter for duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

From the transcript of S2E1 by [Ariane DeVere](https://arianedevere.livejournal.com/27275.html):

> MYCROFT: We destroy this, then. No-one has the information.
> IRENE: Fine. Good idea ... unless there are lives of British citizens depending on the information you’re about to burn.
> MYCROFT: Are there?
> IRENE: Telling you would be playing fair. I’m not playing any more.

So, Irene claims that Mycroft needs the information on her phone available to him, not simply unavailable to her. Recall that at this point, it hasn't been only about the compromising photos of a certain illustrious client. It's been about the wealth of information that Irene has accumulated from different sources, which included, for example, information on Bond Air.

Comment: What you say is true, however the pressure to give into her demands would nonetheless be nullified by the fact that Mycroft does not necessarily need to get the information available instantly. By handing over her phone like that, she lost the ability to engage in blackmail (since she doesn’t have the phone), and it’s not evident that the information that may be important to save British citizens is needed asap, so Mycroft can just drag out the situation until a later time when maybe his folks have figured things out.

Comment: @Whodunit at the very least, Irene isn't  opposed to leaving her phone for an extended period of time with Sherlock, if only for the purpose of letting Mycroft know there's no easy way to access the phone. So in this scene, Irene isn't doing something she hasn't been doing before.

Comment: While the motivation for her leaving her phone with sherlock is made clear to the audience, such “motivation” cannot be said to have been given for why she would just give out her phone to mycroft. She was also confident that she can retrieve her phone back from Sherlock (and she was correct), not known whether she felt the same with Mycroft.